# Returning varchar values and null values

Tags: mysql, null

I am using MySQL to to try and order events by date, and sorting by time. Not all events have a set time however and thus have a null value. My question is how can I build a query that retrieves events with both time fields (set as varchar) and events with a null value, while dropping the events whose time as passed. So far this is what I have yet it is just returning all events. And not dropping events as they pass.

```
    SELECT  `event_title` , DATE_FORMAT( event_date,  '%Y-%b-%d' ) AS formated_event_date, event_date, event_hour
    FROM  `club_events` 
    WHERE  `event_date` > CURDATE( ) -1
    AND HOUR( CURTIME( ) ) > `event_hour`OR HOUR( CURTIME( ) ) >  '' 
    AND club_id !=  '1'
    ORDER BY  `event_date` ASC 
    LIMIT 14;
```

Comment: What is the data type of column `event_date` or can you post some sample values from the column?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use some more brackets:

```
SELECT  `event_title` , DATE_FORMAT( event_date,  '%Y-%b-%d' ) AS formated_event_date, event_date, event_hour
    FROM  `club_events` 
    WHERE  `event_date` > CURDATE( ) -1
    AND (HOUR( CURTIME( ) ) > `event_hour`OR HOUR( CURTIME( ) ) >  '')
    AND club_id !=  '1'
    ORDER BY  `event_date` ASC 
    LIMIT 14;
```

The reason for the additional Brackets is as follows:

since the WHERE clause goes for the date and the second condition is either a set time or an empty time, it would help to use brackets like: WHERE condition_a AND (condition_b OR condition_c) instead of WHERE condition_a AND condition_b OR condition_C which produces not the same result.

but it really would be great to have some sample data and the expected results.

Comment: since the where clause goes for the date and the second condition is either a set time or an empty time, it would help to use brackets like: WHERE condition_a AND (condition_b OR condition_c) instead of WHERE condition_a AND condition_b OR condition_C which produces not the same result.

Comment: Add this to your answer than explaining through a comment.